# Why does the sign change here in a perturbation derivation?

Tags: perturbation-theory

I am studying Lindstedt's method in Gregory classical mechanics (great book). I don't understand a perhaps simple algebraic simplification.
Why does the sign change here? Is this an approximation as well?

[image]

$$ 1/(1+(3/8)x)=1/(1-(3/8)x) $$ is true for small $x$ if I believe correctly

Comment: Have you learned about [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't recognize it. You mean the following right? $\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+...$

Comment: Yes. But I recommend memorizing the more-general series for $(1+x)^\alpha$ because you’ll use it a lot in physics.